# Touch events on UICollectionView causing delegate methods to not be called

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have a UICollectionView set up in which I have cells. I want to tap these cells to play a sound, and also have the ability to drag these cells into a different view to drop those sounds in.

To play sounds, I use the -collectionView:collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath method. And to implement the drag functionality, I used custom login in the touchesBegan, touchesMoved etc. methods.

However, if I have the methods touchesBegan, touchesMoved, the UICollectionView delegate methods never get called. Is there a way I can delay the touch events being delivered until the delegate methods have failed? Or if I use touch events, do I have to implement custom logic to detect a tap on cell too?

Comment: Do you pass touches further, calling super?

Comment: Nope. I just discovered, on further searching for UITableViews that that's what I was missing. It doesn't show on searching for UICollectionView though. Would you like to put it in as the answer?